# is this just the way R works? referencing list item, names(list[x]), lapply + functions + write table

Tags: r, plyr, lapply, summary, write.table

Is there a way to print to file the result of ddply and a list of dfs in a single call to lapply?

example df

```
m<-rep(c("a1","a2","a3","b1","b2","b3","c1","c2","c3"),2)
n<-rep(c(rep(letters[1],3),rep(letters[2],3),rep(letters[3],3)),2)
o<-rep(c("2009","2010"),9)
p<-c(rep("width",9),rep("depth",9))
r<-c(sample((100:200),9),sample((20:50),9))
s<-data.frame(m,n,o,p,r)
colnames(s)<-c("event","site","year","metric","value")
s

u<-split(s,s$year)
```

This function works fine in two steps:

```
w<-      lapply(u,function(x) { 
             v<-ddply(x,.(metric),
                  summarize, result_var_all=var(value))

                  })

sapply(names(w), function(x){ write.csv(w[x],file=paste(x,'.csv'))})
```

But is it possible to combine these steps, more like:

```
lapply(u,function(x) { 
             v<-ddply(x,.(metric),
                  summarize, result_var_all=var(value))

                  write.table(v,file=paste(names(u[x]),'.csv'))})
```

Which doesn't work. I think I understand why, if x is a new list.  Subbing names(x[1]) for u[x] does run but writes the first field name as the file title, and looks like it generates just one output file instead of splitting output files by year.

Is the issue mixing dfs and lists given

```
names(u)
names(u[1])
```

Does x not have a name?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the way `R` works.

Solution is to use `Map` or `names()` (as you did in part of your question)

### Map

```
Map(names(u), u, f = function(xn,x)  {
        v <- ddply(x, .(metric),summarize, result_var_all=var(value))
        write.csv(v, file = sprintf('%s.csv',xn))
        v})
```

### lapply + names

```
lapply(names(u), FUN = function(xn,x)  {
        v <- ddply(x[[xn]], .(metric),summarize, result_var_all=var(value))
        write.csv(v, file = sprintf('%s.csv',xn))
        v}, x = u)
```